# Dart Extension issue

Tags: flutter, dart

Based on online videos this code should show 'gradients' property but it just shows the 'lerp' method. I am currently running Dart v2.9.1 and Flutter v1.20.2.

[image]

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a static member to the original class. Extensions add instance methods to the class, and that's it. In this case, you would have to give your extension a name:

```dart
extension LinearGradientExt on LinearGradient { ...
```

and then access the static member with `LinearGradientExt.gradients`.

Comment: That’s what I did with ColorExt.fromHex, I guess there is no other way to do that.